# Dynamics CRM 2015 Reports - Grouping Cases by Parent Account

Tags: reporting, dynamics-crm-2015

I've been tasked with migrating our companies CRM from a custom built internal solution to Dynamics CRM 2015. So far I've come a fair way figuring out things, but reporting has got me a little stuck.

What we're looking to do is to report on the following and grouped in this manner.

Parent Account
Sub Account
Cases Related to Sub Account

I'm not sure which reporting method would best suit my needs and if I'm just missing something using the grouping method on the report builder.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on standard relationships (adjust according to your customizations):

```
Primary record type: Account
Related record type: Cases (Customer)

Grouping #1 : Related to Account - Parent Account - Account Name
Grouping #2 : Account - Account Name
Columns: Pick from Case
```